# Applying for Spain Student Visa from USA but I've overstayed in the past

Tags: usa, visa, student-visa, spain, overstay

I'm applying for a year-long student visa for Spain (Madrid), all my records and documents are fine. I have no problem with any sort of requirement for the visa (passport, background check, etc); however, I've been to Spain this year already and I overstayed the 90-day limit by about 2 weeks.  I never stayed there for more than 90 days consecutively if that helps, I did leave the Schengen zone in the middle of my stay and had no problems when I went through the airport to go back to the US. I'm interested to know how much I should be worried about my visa application, I know Spain is very relaxed but I'm still nervous. Somebody mentioned I could get a new passport so that the stamps wouldn't be visible but that just seems sketchy as they could look up my past travels and then wonder why I have a new passport all of a sudden. I know my decision to overstay was absolutely idiotic but any advice would be incredible.

Comment: It will be considered. 2 weeks is not a massive overstay. One reason why Americans are so often allowed to remain visa-free nationals for most countries is because even in the infrequent cases of overstays, those overstays are for usually just a few days. I think your best bet will be to just go for it. You are wise not to waste your time trying anything dodgy like getting a new passport. Not only is it an unnecessary waste of time and money, it would be of no use anyway for the reasons you state.

Comment: Right, that's what I was hoping for. I guess there's only way to figure out, thanks for the insight!!

Answer (score 2):

Overstay is not an issue as long as you can provide a valid reason for the same, What I would suggest is to explain the reason for overstay in your letter of intent/ statement of purpose when submitting the visa application to explain your situation to the visa officer.